# Здравствуйте, проблема с пользовательской функцией, пытаюсь сделать функцию на вывод матрицы

Tags: c++, функции, матрицы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void vivod(double** x[10][10],int stl1, int str1);

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int str1, stl1, str2, stl2;
    double** x, ** y, ** um;
    cout << "Введите количество строк первой матрицы: ";
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов первой матрицы: ";
    cin >> stl1;
    str2 = stl1;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов второй матрицы: ";
    cin >> stl2;
    if (str1 != stl2)
    {
        cout << "Умножить нельзя!";
        return 0;
    }
     //ввод матрицы 1
    x = new double* [str1];
    cout << "Введите элементы первой матрицы" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1; i++)
    {
        x[i] = new double[stl1];
        for (int j = 0; j < stl1; j++)
        {
            cout << "x[" << i << "][" << j << "]= ";
            cin >> x[i][j];
        }
    }
   
    vivod (x); // здесь красный x
}
   
 void vivod(double** x[10][10], int stl1, int str1)
    {
       x = new double* [str1]; // здесь красное равно
        for (int i = 0; i < str1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < stl1; j++)
                cout << x[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: double** x[10][10] это не C++ а C в этом основная проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пишите так:

```
void vivod(double** x[10][10], ...)
```

`x` - это параметр, который является указателем на указатели на массив из 10 элементов на массив из 10 элементов. В общем 4 мерный массив.

Чтобы передавать в функцию матрицу динамического размера нужно писать так:

```
void vivod(double** x, ...)
```

Так же у вас функция `vivod` принимает 3 аргумента, а вы передаете всего один.

Я так думаю, вам нужно передавать так же `stl1` и `str1`.

```cpp
vivod(x, stl1, str1);
```

Еще я заметил, что ваша функция `vivod` предназначенная для вывода матрицы, зачем то внутри себя затирает переданный в нее указатель на матрицу, выделяя по новой память на `str1` динамических массивов. И даже это у вас не сработает, т.к. вы не выделили память под сами массивы.

В общем для вывода матрицы, вам не нужно затирать указатель на нее выделяя память, так что просто удалите строчку:

```
x = new double* [str1]; // здесь красное равно
```

из функции `vivod`.

В итоге получаем такую функцию:

```
void vivod(double** x, int stl1, int str1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stl1; j++)
            cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Так же не забудьте заменить строчку перед `main`:

```
void vivod(double** x[10][10], int stl1, int str1);
```

на:

```
void vivod(double** x, int stl1, int str1);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @SavageCrown пожалуйста выберите один из двух ответов, как "Правильный ответ" :) это будет лучшая благодарность.

Answer (score 0):

В C++ должно быть так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void vivod(vector<vector<double>>& x);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int str1, stl1, str2, stl2;
    vector<vector<double>> x, y, um;
    cout << "Введите количество строк первой матрицы: ";
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов первой матрицы: ";
    cin >> stl1;
    str2 = stl1;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов второй матрицы: ";
    cin >> stl2;
    if (str1 != stl2)
    {
        cout << "Умножить нельзя!";
        return 0;
    }
    //ввод матрицы 1
    x.resize(str1);
    cout << "Введите элементы первой матрицы" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str1; i++)
    {
        x[i].resize(stl1);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < stl1; j++)
        {
            cout << "x[" << i << "][" << j << "]= ";
            cin >> x[i][j];
        }
    }

    vivod(x); // здесь красный x
}

void vivod(vector<vector<double>> const& x)
{
    for (auto& row : x)
    {
        for (auto e : row)
            cout << e << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы используете `vector`? Автор вопроса вряд ли еще не знаком с такими структурами, да и толку мала в этом.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков затем, что это C++. И если вас устраивают утечки памяти, то меня нет.

Comment: А как же `delete`?

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, уже часов восемь провозился с этой матрицей, два дня угрохал и без толку. Теперь всё работает!

Comment: @ПавелЕриков А где он в исходном коде?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков ну это ошибка автора, что не добавил освобождение памяти. Почему вы думаете, что автор идеальный код скинул?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков это ошибка автора, которую и вы не заметили. Если вас в C устраивают утечки памяти, то это не значит, что так надо делать и в C++.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков я ничего не пропустил мой ответ отвечает на поставленный вопрос, а не находит все ошибки в коде. Пожалуйста хватит писать "если вас устраивают утечки памяти"... Ладно тут не о чем разговаривать.